# What does Samba need from LDAP for a valid account?

Tags: ldap, samba, openldap, truenas

I have inherited an OpenLDAP system, coupled to a FreeNAS and it is quite a headache to create users all the time. I just want to create a user that can access its own `homes` share.

I have a working user in my LDAP that I almost copied to the new one, but somehow it is still missing information. This is the error message I get when trying to mount the share:

```
[2015/07/31 08:42:49.172906,  1] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:3178(lp_do_parameter)
  WARNING: The "idmap gid" option is deprecated
[2015/07/31 08:42:49.212652,  1] ../source3/auth/server_info.c:407(samu_to_SamInfo3)
  Failed to get groups from sam account.
[2015/07/31 08:42:49.212748,  0] ../source3/auth/check_samsec.c:492(check_sam_security)
  check_sam_security: make_server_info_sam() failed with 'NT_STATUS_INTERNAL_DB_CORRUPTION'
```

I got here by trying to mimic the working user, but I don't seem to be able to get all attributes. Also, the attributes I am still missing seem to be completely unrelated to this message. Actually, I am stuck now.

Any ideas or pointers to get me going?

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar situation and I solved my problem.
I am happy that my solution helps you.

My situation was that I failed to login by smbclient with the following logs:

> [2015/11/22 20:41:59.373496,  1] auth/server_info.c:526(samu_to_SamInfo3)
>     Failed to get groups from sam account.
>   [2015/11/22 20:41:59.373625,  0] auth/check_samsec.c:492(check_sam_security)
>     check_sam_security: make_server_info_sam() failed with 'NT_STATUS_INTERNAL_DB_CORRUPTION'

It was the group config. that should be changed.
In my case, I manage my LDAP accounts with LDAP ACCOUNT MANAGER (LAM)
In LAM, I added `samba3 extension` to the primary group of the user which is tried to use.

In other words, Do you have 'sambaSID' in the group you want to use?
The 'Group' section in 'http://pig.made-it.com/samba-accounts.html' may help you.